# On a Flutter widget this dart error comes - Expected a value of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am very new to flutter. I am trying to create List view with Dynamically generated DropDownButton & And Label .No matter what I do this error occurs and dropdown items not updating.

```
Expected a value of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

This is my listview builder code

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: tasksLength,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    String roleId = taskRoles[index]['roleId'];
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _userList = [DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: '', child: Text('Loading..'))].toList();
    if (usersList['roles'] != null && usersList['roles'][roleId] != null) {
      _userList = usersList['roles'][roleId]['users'].map((item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: item['id'],child: Text(item['name'].toString()));
        }).toList();
    }
    return UserSelect(userList: _userList);
  },
),
```

This is my widget class with the DropDownbutton

```
class UserSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>? userList =
      [DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: '', child: Text('Loading..'))].toList();

  UserSelect({this.userList});
  @override
  _UserSelectState createState() => _UserSelectState();
}

class _UserSelectState extends State<UserSelect> {
  String _selected_user = '';
  String _roleName = 'User Role';
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _userList =
      [DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: '', child: Text('Loading..'))].toList();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(UserSelect oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.userList != widget.userList) {
      _userList = widget.userList!;
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          _roleName,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Bilo',
            fontSize: 16,
            color: const Color(0xff3b3e51),
            letterSpacing: 0.224,
            height: 1.5,
          ),
          textHeightBehavior:
              TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            color: const Color(0xfff6f6f6),
          ),
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
              isExpanded: true,
              value: (_selected_user.length > 0) ? _selected_user : null,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              iconSize: 24,
              elevation: 16,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
              hint: new Text("Select User"),
              underline: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.white24,
              ),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _selected_user = newValue!;
                });
              },
              items: _userList),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Some of codes unnecessary I tried by best to skip this error that is why some junk codes are there.

Please help me to fix this issue or show me right direction.

Comment: Try removing all those `.toList()` because the values are already of type list and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the `.toList();` method calls here:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _userList =
      [DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: '', child: Text('Loading..'))].toList();
```

toList() in dart returns a list with the type that's supplied to its type parameter. [Documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html)

When not supplied with a type parameter, I would assume that the toList() method's return type is `dynamic`.

You can just remove the `toList()` method call altogether, as you already placed the DropDownMenuItem into a list by placing it between the `[square brackets]`! Ironically, the type would've been inferred by the list declaration before you overwrote it with `toList()` and made it dynamic :')

If you DO need to do it this way, you can simply add `[items ...].toList<DropdownMenuItem>()` which will correctly return a list of type DropdownMenuItem :)